# How to avoid duplicating when parsing HTML table useing TRY EXCEPT

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to parse HTML table using Beautifulsoup:

```
from ast import arg
from re import I
from urllib import response
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import mysql.connector
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html
#from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc


#from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
#from telebot import types
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
password = "********"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#options.add_argument("--headless")
path = (r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options = options)
url = "https://w8shippingge.com/customer-zone/"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.NAME,'login').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-block"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input').submit()


data = []
driver.get('https://w8shippingge.com/customer-zone/')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"autos"})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    all_td = row.find_all('td')
    arguments = [x for x in all_td]
    data.append(arguments)
    gh=[e[3] for e in data if len(e) > 3] 
    images=[e[1] for e in data if len(e) > 1] 
    for k, i in zip(gh, images):
        try:
           print(k.text, i.a.img['src'])
        except:
            pass
```

What i try to do, is that i want to get result of each row like this: [**Car name** and **Link of the image**] e.g.:

[2017 VOLKSWAGEN TOUAREG https://ggautoexport.com//Images/auto/762850/220210-8386705.jpg]
[2018 TOYOTA CAMRY ]
[2017 VOLKSWAGEN TOUAREG https://ggautoexport.com//Images/auto/762850/220210-8386705.jpg]

and so on till the and of table.

when there is no link of the image i have to get only car name, but i can not.

Comment: share page link

Comment: You have to sign in to see table, that's why i shared part of the table :(

Comment: please include the imports that you have used so that the problem can be reproduced:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: YOU have to share full code it is not appropiate way to ask queston

Comment: I have changed my question with full code @Amen Aziz, don't ask me Password please :D

Comment: what tabe you extract from page I have not seen any table?

Comment: What is your exact error message/traceback?

Comment: This question is vage, however I will do an attempt `for k, i in zip (gh, images):
    if i.a.img['src']:
        print(k.text, i.a.img['src'])
    else:
        print(k.text)`

Comment: @Rivered Thank you, it is vague, bcz i can not post Password and you can not check exact results. But thank you, you pointed me what i have to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thaks to @Rivered , i added my code what he suggested and got resulted:

```
from ast import arg
from re import I
from urllib import response
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import mysql.connector
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html
#from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc


#from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
#from telebot import types
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

""
password = "*********"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#options.add_argument("--headless")

path = (r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options = options)
url = "https://w8shippingge.com/customer-zone/"
driver.get(url)
#time.sleep(30)

driver.find_element(By.NAME,'login').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-block"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input').submit()

#urlo = driver.get('https://w8shippingge.com/customer-zone/')


data = []
new_list = []

driver.get('https://w8shippingge.com/customer-zone/')
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"autos"})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')



for row in rows:
    all_td = row.find_all('td')
    arguments = [x for x in all_td]
    data.append(arguments)
gh=[e[1] for e in data if len(e) > 1] 
gj=[e[3] for e in data if len(e) > 3]
gk=[e[5] for e in data if len(e) > 5]

for i, j, g in zip(gh, gj, gk):
    try:
       print(j.text, g.text,  i.a.img['src'])
    except:
        print(j.text, g.text,)
```